# What is the difference between 满足 and 满意?

Tags: meaning, difference, word, nuance

I learned both of these words recently. I asked a Chinese friend what is the difference, and she told me they are "almost the same". I'm wondering how strong the "almost" is here. How interchangeable are 满意 and 满足?

Comment: intransitive "to be satisfied" or adj vs transitive "to satisfy"

Comment: Which is which?

Comment: 满意 and 满足, in that order

Comment: Thanks. Can 满足 also be used intransitively, and if so what's the difference in meaning from 满意？

Comment: 滿意 is an emotion. 滿足 is for fulfilling/satisfying some criteria. You can't say 滿意 to tick off a checklist, that'd be like saying *are your requirements happy/content?*.

Comment: In my view, it is perhaps better understood, for English speakers, if we equate 满足 with "being satisfied", and 满意 as "being pleased"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 满 = to fulfill; to satisfy
>
> 意 = mind; intend; desire; idea
>
> 满意 = be satisfied (of a desire); happy with

Example:

希望我們的服務能使你感到**满意** = Hope our service can make you feel **satisfied**  (happy/ satisfied in your mind)

我們已經給你最好的服務，還**不满意**? = We have given you the best service and you are still **not satisfied**? (unhappy/ not satisfied in your mind)

我們已經給你最好的服務，還**不满足**? = We have given you the best service and you are still **not satisfied**? (still want more)

~

> 足 = enough
>
> 满足 = 1. to satisfy (a need) 2.  be satisfied  (of one's need)

Example:

每小時十五美元的工資無法**满足**生活需求 = A wage of fifteen dollars per hour cannot **satisfy**/ meet the cost of living

非法民工有七美元一小時的工資就很**满足**了 = Illegal migrant workers are **satisfied**/ content with a salary of seven dollars an hour (a need is satisfied/ don't feel needing more)

非法民工有七美元一小時的工資就很**满意**了 = Illegal migrant workers are **satisfied** /happy with a salary of seven dollars an hour (a desire is satisfied/fulfilled)

Comment: I, for one, am quite content with a wage of 15$/hr, but this does answer my question, thank you :)

Comment: 满足 = content, good suggestion